# Use of smoteRegress R package in python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, regression, imbalanced-data, smote

I'm trying to use the R package smoteRegress in python using rpy2.
The function SmoteRegress take the parameter form (formula describing the prediction problem).
This parameter in R is express by the formula Target_Variable~. that mean a generic function of the indipendent variable "Target_Variable" respect to the other variable of dataframe.
How can I deal with this in python?

Thanks